# Decimal number conversion VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is an example of the table I have:

[image]

When I try to divide the whole "I" column by a number, I get an Incompatibility error since Excel uses Commas instead of dots for decimals. Any one-liner to change the format of the column without looping please ? or any easy alternative solutions

Comment: With ms 365 use `=NUMBERVALUE(I1:I19,".")/<YourNumber>`

Comment: R u sure this method exists in VBA ? I receive an error as Sub or Function undefined

Comment: Here it takes 3 mandatory arguments : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.worksheetfunction.numbervalue

Comment: It's a formula in Excel, not VBA. For the formula variant at least the 3rd parameter is definately optional. Also appears to be the case in VBA `r = Application.NumberValue([I1:I19], ".")` return an array 'r' with the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next VBA way:

```
Sub ChangeDecimalSep()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
 lastRow = ws.Range("I" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = ws.Range("I2:I" & lastRow)
 
 With rng
    .replace ".", ",", xlPart
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
End Sub
```

The above code supposes that the column to be processed is "I:I", starting from its second row, in the first one being the header. If different, it would be easy to adapt it, I think...

Comment: My solution is very similar but neither mine nor yours works. I mean it does enable basic arithmetics, but try for example doing a MATCH on some of the numbers =MATCH(84964,25,I:I,0) and you get #N/A. Is there a way to actually convert the text to numbers? I don't think this does it.

Comment: @FaneDuru 's solution works just fine, but above all the replaced cells there a warning box saying that 'The cell's value has been stocked as a text instead of number'. Nevertheless, my division still works even though the cell type became a text

Comment: @Keyser Soze Let me add another code line, which I think may solve your problem...

Comment: @andrewb I think now it already change `NumberFormat` and `.value = .value` will force it to be treated as a number. Even if all the range used to be formatted as Text.

Comment: @FaneDuru could you test if the MATCH in my earlier comment finds the number which had the decimal separator replaced? Maybe it's something weird on my end. Also I can't apply number filters to the column so the values are still treated as text. Arithmetics does work.

Comment: @andrewb I do not have comma as decimal separator... But you can see that they are numbers. You can make arithmetical operations with them. Did you test the updated code? Changing `NumberFormat` and having `.value = .value` will eliminate the problem you are talking about...

Comment: @FaneDuru my decimal separator is comma and while your code make the arithmetics work, the other problems still persist. It's ok, I might post my own question about this some time.

Comment: @andrewb Having comma as decimal separator, because of localization you should also have ";" as list separator (if not mandatory). Otherwise `Find` may be confused, `thinking` that you use 4 parameters instead of three...

Comment: I do use ; as list separator. I put commas in the comment for your convenience :)

Comment: I just noticed a weird behaviour with @FaneDuru 's code, a lot of decimals get their dot/comma completely removed ! These numbers usually have 5 decimal digits or more & they become XX E^14

Comment: Using `=MATCH(84964.25,I:I,0)` works as it should on my installation. I do not know what's happening in yours. Try another value.

Comment: @Keyser Soze They are not removed, I think... If the number is larger then 12 digits, Excel automatically convert (only) its format in scientific. The original decimals are there. In some other cases the **displayed** number of decimals is not for all of them. Try playing with the number group of Home ribbon tab increasing the number of decimals. You can also format the numbers, something as "0000000000000.0000000000", if convenient. The above code only transforms the strings containing comma in numeric values. Excel (General format) guesses what is it about and try 'optimizing'...

Comment: @Keyser Soze It shouldn't touch the comma being thousand separator... Now I am leaving my office. Anyhow, I designed the code to solve the numbers you show in your picture. Is there any problem with one of them?

Comment: Maaan it made me goes crazy for 1h ... At the end all I had to do was switch "xlPart" to "xlWhole" in the replace arguments ! It even solved the text/number format problem

Comment: @FaneDuru I can't seem to find how to send a private message in here, but if u would let me I would send u 10 bucks with pleasure for being my guardian angel these past 2 days hah. Sincerely, thanks

Comment: @Keyser Soze 1. I cannot understand how replacing `xlPart` with `xlWhole` solved the problem... The comma is only a part of the string... Anyhow, it is good to check the consistency of your data. If the initial text also had a comma "," as thousand separator, Excel could interpret it as decimal separator. a) Where from did you import the data in discussion? It would be good to check such cases against that database. b) If you have it I can try showing you how to change the numbers format **there**. To be correctly imported. I am glad I could help, so no need to send anything.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you could apply the Excel's `NUMBERVALUE()` formula where you assert that there could be a decimal point:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(<YourRange>,".")/<YourNumber>
```

The VBA-Equivalent could be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long: lr = ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("I2:I" & lr)
Dim nr As Long: nr = 5

rng.Value = Application.Evaluate("=NUMBERVALUE(" & rng.Address & ",""."")/" & nr)

End Sub
```

[image] >> [image]

---

I opted to use `Application.Evaluate` method because you mentioned you also need to devide the values by a static number. If you didn't have to do so, you could opt for:

```
With Application
    rng.Value = .Index(.NumberValue(rng, "."),0,1)
End With
```

[image] >> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just select the whole column, press **Ctrl + h**, put period in "Find what" and comma in "Replace with". Press "Replace all" and problem solved. Excel will automatically convert the values to numbers.

This is the vba equivalent:

```
Sub periodToComma()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Columns("A:A")
    
    targetRange.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=Application.DecimalSeparator, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    
End Sub
```

But this will not convert the values to numbers for some reason. There are some solutions floating around like adding

```
With targetRange
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

But that does not work for me.

However, if all you need is to perform division or other basic arithmetics on the values in the column, this will work.

Comment: I would rather have it inside a VBA Macro, so that the end-user doesn't have to do it himself by hand each time. Do u know the equivalent of what u mentioned in VBA ?

Comment: @KeyserSoze you can just record a macro while doing what I described. Unfortunately, the produced code does not convert the values to numbers like the manual process does for some mysterious reason. You will be able to perform calculations on the column but some formulas might not work as expected and if you needed to filter the column, only text filters will be available. I don't know how to solve this. There are solutions around but none worked for me.